# Associative Key to Key map in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, containers

I'm searching for something like a "Key to Key" map in C++.

My intention is as follows:

- Each Key - either on the "left" or "right" side is unique
- The key of the left side can be looked up by the key of the right side et vice versa

As an example and to make my intention more clear, in code, it would probably look like:

```
key2key<int, string> myMap; // int maps to string, string to int

myMap.insert(0, "zero");
myMap.insert(1, "one");
myMap.insert(2, "two");

myMap.insert(1, "zero"); // would throw an error
myMap.insert(9, "one"); // would throw an error as well

cout << myMap.lookupLeft(1) << endl; // prints "one"
cout << myMap.lookupRight("one") << endl; // prints "1"
```

Of course I could go ahead and implement something like this on my own, but is there anything existing out there?
I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so maybe it's possible to modify or reuse standard STL containers or boost.

Why do I think that it is useful?

Imagine you're reading a configuration file and you also want to write or make changes to this config file.
This config file might contain some fields which internally in c++ are represented as type safe enum classes.
Using a "Key to Key" map is a very lightweight generator and type converter of theses values.

```
enum class DebugLevel {error, warning, debug};
const key2key<DebugLevel, string> debugLevelMap = {
  {DebugLevel::error, "error"},
  {DebugLevel::warning, "warning"},
  {DebugLevel::debug, "debug"},
}

DebugLevel foo = debugLevelMap.lookupRight("error");
string bar = debugLevelMap.lookupLeft(DebugLevel::warning);
```

Comment: You could simply use two maps.  If the objects are large, consider placing them somewhere else (eg in a vector) and only storing pointers in the map.  Or use shared pointers.

Comment: But this does not prevent that one map could potentially contain two equivalent values.

Comment: You'd need to check that neither of the maps already contains the key / value before you insert to any of them.

Comment: Take a look at boost.bimap.

Comment: [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Oh noes, it does not support those elegant initializer lists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was posting my first answer, I was not aware that a thing like [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) exists.  I agree that rolling your own bidirectional map is probably inferior to using the presumably very high quality Boost implementation.  Even more so if your project already has a dependency on Boost.  If your biggest concern is the lack of an initializer list constructor for `boost::bimap`, you can easily add that functionality as a factory function.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
boost::bimap<T1, T2>
make_bimap(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<T1, T2>> initlist)
{
  using bimap_type = boost::bimap<T1, T2>;
  using value_type = typename bimap_type::value_type;
  bimap_type bimap {};
  for (const auto& iter : initlist)
    {
      if (!bimap.insert(value_type {iter.first, iter.second}).second)
        throw std::invalid_argument {"already mapped"};
    }
  return bimap;
}

int
main()
{
  using namespace std::literals;
  const auto bimap = make_bimap<int, std::string>({
      {0, "zero"s},
      {1, "one"s},
      {2, "two"s},
   // {1, "zero"s},  // would throw
   // {9, "one"s},   // would throw
  });
  std::cout << bimap.left.at(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << bimap.right.at("one") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
one
1
```

Credit for initially mentioning `boost::bimap` goes to @[Pradhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862351/pradhan).

Comment: about detecting the duplicates, there's precisely zero difference to semantics of std::map. Just call `insert`/`emplace` and check the return value

Comment: @sehe Thanks, I supposed that it should be easily possible but wasn't able to find out how in yesterday's hurry.  Updated the answer according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement this using two `std::map`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class BidirectionalMap
{

private:

  std::map<T1, T2> lhs2rhs_ {};
  std::map<T2, T1> rhs2lhs_ {};

public:

  BidirectionalMap()
  {
  }

  // This is not thread-safe, if you need thread-safety, use a mutex.
  void
  insert(const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs)
  {
    if (this->lhs2rhs_.count(lhs) || this->rhs2lhs_.count(rhs))
      throw std::invalid_argument {"already mapped"};
    this->lhs2rhs_[lhs] = rhs;
    this->rhs2lhs_[rhs] = lhs;
  }

  T2
  lookupLeft(const T1& lhs) const
  {
    return this->lhs2rhs_.at(lhs);
  }

  T1
  lookupRight(const T2& rhs) const
  {
    return this->rhs2lhs_.at(rhs);
  }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void
demo_insert(BidirectionalMap<T1, T2>& mymap, const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs)
{
  try
    {
      mymap.insert(lhs, rhs);
    }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
      std::cerr << "cannot insert (" << lhs << ", " << rhs << "): "
                << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}


int
main()
{
  using namespace std::literals;
  BidirectionalMap<int, std::string> mymap {};
  demo_insert(mymap, 0, "zero"s);
  demo_insert(mymap, 1, "one"s);
  demo_insert(mymap, 2, "two"s);
  demo_insert(mymap, 1, "zero"s);
  demo_insert(mymap, 9, "one"s);
  std::cout << mymap.lookupLeft(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << mymap.lookupRight("one") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
cannot insert (1, zero): already mapped
cannot insert (9, one): already mapped
one
1
```

Comment: First i was not convinced of this solution as i don't like cooking my own soup for trivial problems but maybe it's really the easiest way to realize it. This solution could also easily be extended by initializer lists. Let me sleep on it for a night.

Comment: @rralf If the lack of the initializer list constructor is your major objection, have a look at my other answer.